# a model with several one-to-many relationships

Tags: go, go-gorm

I'm using gorm to represents a model and do several operations.

The model contains an entity which has a one-to-many relationship with another entity an this has a one-to-many relatioship with another entity too.
Something link this:

```
+---------+              +------------+              +------------+
| entity1 |  one-to-many | entity 2   |  one-to-many | entyty3    |
|         |------------->|  entity1ID |------------->|  entity2ID |
+---------+              +------------+              +------------+
```

When I run a complete update operation of the model the final state of postgres is inconsistent.

I haven't found info about gorm samples involving complex models. Most samples only contains one entity and a few samples contains  models with two entities.
I'm starting to think that gorm isn't for complex projects and models.

How can I do an update operation with a consistent result in the storage?

Comment: Are you fetch before update or update by Id with new child ?

Comment: in the update process for entity1, if you remove some childs, entity2 has row with unlinked entity1ID and entity3 is not updated

Comment: Are you fetch entity with preloading child entities ? Can you explain this inconsistent case with an example in your question

Comment: After update, I can find orphan entity2 elements. First of update, I load the entity with preloading child entities, then I update the result model and the update de model with save. For example, removed items are not deleted from database

Comment: Which method are you using for update when this scenario happened?

Comment: Update or Save methods